# Returning DataTable or DataSet from EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a number of Functions in a Data Access Layer that are currently using ADO.Net, but I'm investigating how to rewrite these to use EntityFramework in stead.

Since most of these functions return DataTable objects, it would be nice to be able to keep returning DataTable (at least for a period). Let's say that one of the functions look like this:

```
public async Task<DataTable> GetGoblinsAsync(CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    using (var conn = GetConnection())
    {
    await conn.OpenAsync(cancelToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var command =  new SqlCommand("select * from [SomeGoblinTable]", conn); 
    using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(cancelToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(reader);
        return dt;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the framework version you use ?

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of any question about converting `IEnumerable` to DataTable, because that's what it is basically. There must be a couple. There's no built-in EF function.

Comment: @DarkkL .NET Framework 4.8. Is this different in .NET (Core) ?

Answer (score 1):

Using FastMember (nuget) you can do:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(source))
            dt.Load(reader);
        return dt;
    }
}
```